# Add files to current classpath of jar file

Tags: java, jar, properties, classpath

i have a jar created by a **spring batch app**, i am using a config.proprerties but i need that this file is located **outside** from jar.
i have the config.properties en the location "var/user/config.properties" and i have run the jar using the **command:**

java -classpath "/var/user/config.properties" batch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar es.exp.exp.config.BatchConfiguration someJob date=20210115 systemDate=15

But i thinck that the argument -classpath set all classpath, i mean that classpath argument remove the jar classpath and put only /var/user/config.properties in classpath.
and i don't need this, i need the classpath to be "actual jar Classpath + /var/user/config.properties".
any idea?

Sorry for my english, is not my native languaje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classpath elements in `-classpath` (or `-cp`) are separated by ":" on Linux, or ";" in Windows.

Also, if you want `config.properties` to be accessible in the classpath you don't need to add the file in the path, but the directory containing the file.

Try with:

```
java -cp /var/user:batch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar es.tirea.cicosgw.config.BatchConfiguration someJob date=20210115 systemDate=15
```

Comment: it works, thanks. it just that is necessary put the main class before the es.exp.exp.config.BatchConfiguration.